# Is there a reason why the program is not able to compare the users input and the file?

Tags: python

I cannot see a reason why my program isnt able to compare the users input and such. My program is a Username/Password program for a OS i am working on i am not sure why it isnt working it always fires back with incorrect even when it is correct?

```
import os
isuserempty = os.stat("Username.txt").st_size == 0
ispassempty = os.stat("Password.txt").st_size == 0
if isuserempty or ispassempty == True:
    print("Hello, new user create a username and password.")
    newusername = input("Enter your new username: ")
    NewUser = open("Username.txt" , "a")
    NewUser.write(newusername)
    NewUser.close()
    newpassword = input("Enter your new password: ")
    NewPass = open("Password.txt" , "a")
    NewPass.write(newpassword)
    NewPass.close()
    print("You now have a new Username and Password!")
    print("You are now logged in!")
elif isuserempty or ispassempty == False:
    truePass = open("Password.txt", "r")
    trueUser = open("Username.txt", "r")
    print("Enter your Username.")
    userUserName = input("Enter:")
    print("Enter your password.")
    userPass = input("Enter:")
    if userUserName == trueUser and userPass == truePass:
        print("Correct! Logging in...")
    if userUserName != trueUser or userPass != truePass:
        print("Incorrect!")
```

Comment: I don't know python, but I'm pretty sure that `truePass` and `trueUser` are file handlers, you need to read their contents, so your condition should look something like `if userUserName == trueUser.read() and userPass == truePass.read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `truePass` and `trueUser` are variables of type `TextIOWrapper` (files) which you currently compare to strings. In your `elif` block, read the contents of your files like this before doing the comparison.

```
pass_file = open("Password.txt", "r")
truePass=pass_file.read()
user_file = open("Username.txt", "r")
trueUser = user_file.read()
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! Would upvote but my reputation isnt high enough :(